# Display formatted Text in iOS App?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, ios7

**Problem:** I want to display formatted text in a iOS App. The formatted text should be entered in a server backend in a Word-like editor. The text should then be displayed in the app using a stylesheet.

**Proposed solution:** 
- on the server backend site I could  use a rich text editor customized to the controls I need and hiding the controls I do not need. 
- the rich text editor produces html text which is stored in a text field of a mysql database
- on the App side I could use a UIWebView to display the html text and a css stylesheet to customize the layout

Note: Markdown would only be an option of there is a WYSIWYG editor for it.

1. Is the solution I described a proper way of solving the problem?
2. Are there anything I am missing?
3. Should I store the HTML in my database or in a separate file with a link to the file in the database?

Comment: My opinion would be to use markdown to do it - there are markdown parsers for iOS. It's lightweight, can be stored in plaintext on your back-end, and doesn't require heavy parsing.

Comment: 1. Is there a WYSIWYG editor for Markdown? 2. Would you recommend to store markdown in a mysql database text field?